# Select rows where variable is found in a comma delimited cell

Tags: mysql

I have a a table that has a cell on each row that has several comma-delimited values in it, like `TAGS=1,2,3,4,5`. How can I select all rows that contain for example the TAG 5?

I have tried `SELECT * FROM videos WHERE tags LIKE %$id%`, however I get into problems if `$id`=2 for example, as 12 or 22 get selected too...

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set up the `where` statement as:

```
where concat(',', tags, ',') like concat('%,', 5, ',%')
```

In your case, this would be:

```
where concat(',', tags, ',') like concat('%,', $id, ',%')
```

That is, you want to be sure that the delimiters are around the value you are looking for.  So, the right-hand side is evaluated as `'%,5,%'`.  Then, you need to be sure that every element of the list is surrounded by delimiters, include the first and last elements.

Comment: but this way the data structure would need to be `,1,2,3,4,5,` wouldn't it?

Comment: @Michal . . . The query attaches the extra commas for both the list and the element.  Typically when items are in a comma-delimited list, they don't have commas at the beginning and end.

Comment: aha... ok, I'll give this a try :)

Answer (score 1):

Ooooh, I did this a long long time ago - and it was the biggest mistake in my life when I thought I was a genius on how I attacked a problem. You see, "Like" is a pretty expensive comparison operator, takes a while for anything to be looked up, especially the minute you put the percentages in there.

You're better off creating a separate table that links the different id to each row, the lookups will be insanely faster.

However, you want to solve the issue above. I'd suggest updating your column to have commas at the beginning or the end, and then search for anything that has a comma before or after it.

e.g.

```
LIKE '%,12,%'
```

Comment: Or Like '12' or Like '%,12' will round it out, but as Duniyadnd says now you need bits of the csv, baaaaaaaaaaaad idea.

Comment: it's an bad idea overall :) but this comes out if clients do not specify the requirements in the beginning...

Answer (score 1):

Use `FIND_IN_SET()` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set
`select * from videos where FIND_IN_SET('22',tags)>0;`
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5a699/1